# Cuando no muestra imágenes ¿es problema de la BD?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, array, imagen, rutas

A través de un formulario en PHP estoy guardando imágenes en el servidor y pasando las rutas a la base de datos. Hasta aqui todo bien.
Pero dichas imágenes no se muestran en una galería,  curiosamente está el enlace de la ruta cuando miro en código de la página pero ni se abre la foto.

La conexión funciona, No hay errores de PHP ni HTML,  por lo que deduzco que tiene que ser algo de la BD. No sé,  codificación , cotejamiento..? dónde lo puedo comprobar? 
Por otro lado las imágenes se recogen en forma multiple en un array, y quizás el el fallo viene  por ahi y falte algo de código. No domino mucho este tema, se agradecerá cualqier ayuda.

[image: (BASE DATOS)]

(PARTE PHP):

```
$consulta ="SELECT avatar,img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,t_avatar,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6 
FROM user WHERE id = ' " . $_GET["id"] . "'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
$fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc();

$avatar= $fila['avatar'];

$img1 = $fila['img1'];
$img2 = $fila['img2'];
$img3 = $fila['img3'];
$img4 = $fila['img4'];
$img5 = $fila['img5'];
$img6 = $fila['img6'];

$t1 = $fila['t1'];
$t2 = $fila['t2'];
$t3 = $fila['t3'];
$t4 = $fila['t4'];
$t5 = $fila['t5'];
$t6 = $fila['t6'];
```

(PARTE HTML)

```html
 <div class="crop" style=" display:none; position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
         <a class="fancybox"  rel="group" href="<?php echo $avatar; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t_avatar; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="crop" style="position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $img1; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t1; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="crop" style="position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $img2; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t2; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="crop" style="position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $img3; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t3; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="crop" style="position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
         <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $img4; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t4; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div> 
        
        <div class="crop" style="position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $img5; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t5; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="crop" style="position:relative; top:1em; width:9em; height:9em;float:left;margin:2px;"> 
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php echo $img6; ?>"><img  src="<?php echo $t6; ?>"  width="100px" height="auto" /></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Lo **primero** que deberías hacer es depurar tus variables, cada una de ellas, usando por ejemplo `var_dump($avatar);` para ver si cada una tiene los datos que realmente esperas o no. Eso es lo primero. Luego podremos ver otras cosas, hasta llegar a un grave error de seguridad que hay en tu consulta. El resultado de esta variable por ejemplo `$t_avatar` lo puedes poner en tu navegador para ver si realmente esas rutas son funcionales, puede que no lo sean porque se construyen por error por porque se encuentran en carpetas bloqueadas o por mil otros motivos.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser un error que sucede en tu navegador. Aprieta botón derecho sobre cualquier parte de la pagina y selecciona "inspeccionar".

Esto abrirá las pestañas de desarrollador de Chrome o Firefox.

En la pestaña "Consola" aparecen los errores y mensajes de desarrollo, A tí te interesa la pestaña "Red" que muestra qué se está cargando y qué no. Es posible que necesites recargar la página para que se active esta pestaña.

¿No se ve la imagen o ni siquiera se carga en el navegador? ¿Se trata de un error de código o de conectividad de red? Etc.

1. Si la imagen se carga, es un problema de HTML: la imagen no se ve.
2. Si la imagen no se carga es un error PHP: el HTML para ver la imagen no se genera correctamente
3. Si la imagen intenta ser cargada pero no se encuentra: Puede ser un error de red o que la ruta a la imagen no es correcta.

Ojalá te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Si estás guardando rutas revisa que sean relativas al `DocumentRoot`de tu servidor, de lo contrario al acceder a los recursos obtendrás los errores:

- `403` -no se tiene permiso para acceder al recurso.
- `402` -no se logra encontrar el recurso.

Sea cuál sea el error la imagen no se visualizará.